# How does UIControl manage its target?

Tags: ios, target, uicontrol

Apple:

```
// the action cannot be NULL. Note that the target is not retained.
- (void)addTarget:(nullable id)target action:(SEL)action forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;
```

Note that the target is not retained.

while in UIControl+BlocksKit.m

```
BKControlWrapper *target = [[BKControlWrapper alloc] initWithHandler:handler forControlEvents:controlEvents];
[handlers addObject:target];
[self addTarget:target action:@selector(invoke:) forControlEvents:controlEvents];
```

so how `UIControl` manage the target,why target not released?

Comment: The UIControl target is not released because it is not retained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `bk_addEventHandler:forControlEvents:` method retains the `BKControlWrapper` instances by adding it to an `NSMutableSet`. That set is retained by the `events` dictionary, which is retained by the control itself, because the dictionary is associated with the control using `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC`.

It's import that the block you pass to `bk_addEventHandler:forControlEvents:` not create a retain cycle. You must do this by making sure the block uses weak references where needed (like if it needs to refer to a view controller than references the control).